# Scala play framework redirect

Tags: scala, playframework

Is there a way to receive a json, format it into a case class, then pass it to another controller via a Redirect?

Example :

```
@Singleton
class SomeController @Inject() extends Controller {

def index = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
  request.body.validate[JsonCaseClass] match {
    case JsSuccess(data, _) =>{
     //Send to another controller
     Redirect(routes.AnotherController.Afunction(data))
     }
     case JsError(errors) => BadRequest("error")
    }
  }
}
```

`AFunction(data)` does some computation and returns an `Ok("Done")`.

I'm using PlayFramework version 2.5.

Comment: Inject the other controller?

Comment: How would this work with a Redirect? My AFunction(data) returns an Action[AnyContent] (Having Injected the controller) and it excpects a String. I'm very new to scala and might be looking at this completely wrong.

Comment: If you're looking to share functionality then decouple what the controller is doing and the reuse the logic?

Comment: @Peter.M look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: @RhysBradbury I would really like to have two seperate controllers. I think it is a lot easier to maintain.

Comment: @RhysBradbury I ended up rewriting a bit of my code and injecting the needed controllers. Thanks for the help.